# Change style for a list of dates in telerik:radcalendar

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datepicker, telerik

I'm working on a WPF application and trying to highlight specific dates in a radcalendar, dates that are calculated in my ViewModel class. These highlighted dates would show the user that he/she has upcoming tasks on those dates. I saw that the best (or maybe only) way for that is to implement a StyleSelector, but I'm not sure how to pass the list of dates from my ViewModel class to the StyleSelector class. Could you give me advice? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hi Kata, you can take a look at examples in microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.styleselector?view=netcore-3.1). Or give us an piece of the code then describe the issues and attempts you've made

Comment: Thanks, I've already went through a lot of microsoft docs, but haven't found any useful stuff. My problem is that I want to apply template only on the specific dates I select into a list in my ViewModel class and in the StyleSelector class I can't reach that list, so I'd like to somehow pass it to that other class.

Comment: could you pass a working example of a calendar you have now? What component are you using, what exactly do you want to color? There are pretty good examples like [this one](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcalendar/styles-and-templates/daybuttonstyleselector). Just change check in `DayButtonStyleSelector `  to `content.Date==DateTime.Now`. Without better description it's hard for me to give more help

Comment: This example would work just fine if I could use my own list of dates in the checking function in DayButtonSelector, like: if(myList.Contains(Content.Date)....then apply some kind of highlighting on that date in the calendar, but I don't know how to pass that list from the ViewModel class into the DayButtonSelector class.

Comment: here you have an [example](https://docs.telerik.com/help/windows-8-xaml/radcalendar-customeventinformation.html) with viewModel. In your case instead of events you just look for DateTime.Now. Could you try it and if you have issues please paste the code for CustomStyleSelector , XAML and ViewModel?

Comment: Sorry, this example does not work in my case, but I found a solution for the problem under this link: https://www.telerik.com/forums/change-date-colors-in-rad-calendar?fbclid=IwAR0bmCS1kXP_xsR4qV4_VSPXSmuIooI4a0iNnjR-HSm_7bCXossgJiZLTKg